# Excel, Frequent string value with IF condition

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, match, mode

I would like to find the modal area code for each ID number in excel.
I have 2 columns

```
ID no.            Area Code
1                 ABC
1                 ABC
1                 ABC
1                 DEF
2                 HIJ
2                 HIJ
2                 KLM
```

So far I am finding the mode of the whole column using:

```
=(INDEX(B:B,MODE(MATCH(B:B,B:B,0))))
```

But I would like all ID no. 1 area codes to be ABC and ID no. 2 to be HIJ

Any advice would be great! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking into pivot tables?

Comment: I couldn't think of anything that wouldn't involve me manually filtering the ID numbers? And it's quite a big data set.

Comment: I'm saying try using pivot tables, I'm pretty sure they can handle your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookup table with the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$13,MODE(IF($A$2:$A$13=D2,MATCH($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,0))))
```

You enter array formulas by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula

In the example shown below the formula would go in `E2` next to the first listed ID and then you would drag it down for all the IDs in the adjacent column.

Example:

[image: Example]